# How can I obtain the current View object on Android OS?

Tags: android

I need to somehow obtain the top level View object of the current application being run. My program is a service that needs to monitor the current application (another application of Activity type) in some way, in order to get its View hierarchy. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this.  For security reasons each application runs as it's own user id and has privacy from the others.